# trouble with padding IE, FF, Chrome

Tags: css

hi guys im having trouble with padding with a input box for my contact page

im working with tables and i cant seem to get the correct padding or margin for my input boxes

here is the site: 217.120.183.184/cdweb/Contact/

please take a look about what i can try to fix this

Greetings,

Darren

Comment: wow... tables... are you building web pages for the year 1998?

Answer (score 0):

I would start again from scratch, you have nested tables and all sorts, which is (technically) bad practice, I would look at using DIV's and CSS to absolutely align your elements.

Answer (score 0):

Correct your table layout, you can't add as many td and colspan on it.

Answer (score 0):

Purely using tables and inline styles (where you have widths and heights etc) is a very outdated practice, and debugging this kind of legacy design isn't so much a case of giving you a couple of rules, but more like saying 'you need to learn a bit more'.

Tables have their place - there's still a number of tricks that are close to impossible without them - but you really need to pick up some better technique.

Probably a good approach is pay someone to setup your page for you in clean css and html, and then see how they did it. There's thousands of services who will do this for you, and your design is not complex, so should be pretty cheap.

The thing is - this appears to be a site which is selling design services. If you're having a lot of trouble getting a simple design like this laid out, then at some point in the future you'll have a much much harder time, unless you bite the bullet, and start to pick up on proper, modern technique.

It's much simpler than it seems - keep things super simple, **and don't forget to use a good CSS reset**. The reset will remove all the table margins and paddings which are part of the browser's user agent styles, and let you define exactly how it should look.

[Eric Meyer's CSS Reset](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/) - not namespaced, resets generally across items.

[YUI3 Reset](http://yuilibrary.com/yui/docs/cssreset/) - namespaced, so you can selectively apply a reset to chunks of the page as required.