# Padding troubles need fix

Tags: firefox, google-chrome, padding, margin

hi guys this is my previous post i really need to get this fixed so im gonna post this here:

[trouble with padding IE, FF, Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10880168/trouble-with-padding-ie-ff-chrome)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the exact problem here, but I guess it's the button.
Try putting position: relative; left: -10px; in your img tag as style.

EDIT: Or maybe a bit more pixels. Fit it to your likes.